# Why variable does not changed after assigning new value?

Tags: php

I have this code which changes the $date variable after submiting the form.

```
<?php 
    $date=date("m/d/Y");
?>

<form action="" method="post">
   <input type='text' value=<?php echo $date ?> name='day1'/>
   <button type='submit' name='btnFilter'>Filter</button>
</form>

<?php
  if(isset($_POST['btnFilter'])){
    $date=$_POST['day1'];
  }
  echo $date;
?>
```

What I wanted to happen is default value of #day1 to be today. And when user change it and submit, page must echo the new date and value in the #day1  must be new user input. But in my code when user submit the form, value of #day1 become today(default value). What do I have to change?

Comment: nice Stealth edit (not marking as an edit) and using answers below. *tsk tsk* Your original post http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32730657/1 did not contain the name attribute for your button. `<button type="submit" id='btnFilter'>Filter</button>`

Comment: Actually I'm sorry for that. I did that because my problem didn't change with those changes.

Comment: you're also going to have problems later on, should you decide to adventure yourself with databases

Comment: @Fred-ii- why is that?

Comment: Because of `("m/d/Y")`

Comment: Still I can't understand problem with that. Please help me

Comment: just visit the mysql.com website, it's all in there. Plus, think about your user input, if someone types in something like "abc" or "123" or "!#$&*" ;-) you need to rethink this, should this be used for a live site. don't let "them" type it in, give them pre-defined choices of valid characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this :

```
<?php 
    $date = date("m/d/Y");

     if(isset($_POST['btnFilter'])){
        $date = $_POST['day1'];
     }

?>

<form action="" method="post">
   <input type="text" value="<?php echo $date ?>" id="day1" name="day1"/>
   <input type="submit" id='btnFilter' name="btnFilter">Filter</button>
</form>
```

You are using id.. that not carry a value with `$_POST`. Assign name to your input tags.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add name to your submit button.
2. Enclose the value for text field with quotes.
3. Give name to your text field. then it will work.

   ```
   <form action="" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="day1" value="<?php echo $date ?>" id="day1"/>
      <button type="submit" name="btnFilter" id='btnFilter'>Filter</button>
   </form>
   ```

> **Note** : What ever you access in `$_POST['']` should be the `name` attribute not `id` attribute of form elements.

Comment: with the change in name for form elements, it should work fine.

Comment: It worked only when @raveenanigam 's method is applied.

Comment: you should keep the php code above form to get desired output, i changed only form part.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are checked isset of btnFilter. Try check for day1 element:

```
<?php 
    $date = date("m/d/Y");
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type='text' value=<?php echo $date ?> name='day1'/>
    <button type='submit' name='btnFilter'>Filter</button>
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['day1'])){
    $date = $_POST['day1'];
}
echo $date;
?>
```